# Are Holograms supposed to blink in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, romulan, section-31

In Star Trek DS9 S07E16 *Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges*, we see that when Dr. Bashir is briefing the director of Section 31 (Sloan,) he's showing him holo images of different Romulans, during which, if we look closely at the "still" holo-images, the images blink. Is it to make the image look more lifelike, or a directing/acting problem?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about Starfleet holograms in general, or just the ones of the Romulans in this specific episode?

Comment: I am talking about the holo-images in general (no, not the ones in holosuites, for they are supposed to appear life-like), i.e. the ones which are, created by, for the lack of a better word, portable devices

Comment: This is literally one of these "blink and you miss it" scenes!

Comment: So it's like this? https://youtu.be/jRGEzAg1FK0

Comment: Holograms do whatever they're programmed to do. Unless the plot requires them to do otherwise. In this particular case, however, it's probably just the actor blinking as he stands there, and it got caught on camera.

Comment: And the director just neglected it, like in all other Series where we see stuff like Camera Cables or Papers inserted below stools to make them level? Star Trek guys really do need to work on this

Comment: the scene with the inactive hologram romulan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwLWpRzMdNY

Comment: Modern phones have a function (distinct from photo and video recording) where they essentially record a really really short video. I believe the intent is that when you take a photo, you can grab a different frame of that video if you catch someone blinking in a group-photo, but I could well imagine that in the far future, still-images are no longer the standard. or that an "idle animation" is normal for holographic reproductions.